# Error SQLSTATE[23000] al intentar agregar un nuevo elemento a mi BD a traves de mi api

Tags: php, android, json, api, slim

Estoy desarrollando una `API` con `slim framework 3` que conecta a una base de datos local. El problema es el siguiente, cuando intento insetar un nuevo elemento me tira el siguiente erro
`{"error": {"text": SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'nombre' cannot be null}` . Comparto el código `PHP`, una imagen de mi tabla y del error.

```
    $this->post('agregar', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    $nombre = $request->getParam('nombre');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO especialidad (nombre) VALUES(:nombre)"; 
    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);

        $stmt->execute(); 

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Especialidad Agregada"}';

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage(). '}';
    }

});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error es claro: `Column 'nombre' cannot be null`. Dado que el código está bien escrito, lo único que podría estar ocurriendo es que estés recibiendo un valor `NULL` aquí: **`$nombre = $request->getParam('nombre');`**. Haz un `var_dump($nombre);` para verificar o mejor un **`var_dump($request);`** para ver ●︵•  lo que hay ahí dentro .

Comment: efectivamente cuando hago un `var_dump($nombre);` el valor es `null` lo q no comprendo es por q no me lo toma

Comment: El `var_dump($request);` ¿qué arroja?

Comment: Me devuelve 9000 lineas

Comment: ¿9,000 líneas? ¿Necesitas 9,000 líneas ahí? Creo que eso hay que optimizarlo. No puedes traer 9,000 líneas sólo para sacar un nombre e insertarlo en la BD. ¿No crees?

Comment: Si no me equivoco agregando esta linea al principio `$esp = json_decode($request->getBody());` eliminando `$nombre = $request->getParam('nombre');` y modificando `$stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $esp->nombre);` se solucionaria el problema

Comment: No lo sé, tu código parece indicar que estás trabajando con algún framework el cual desconozco. De todos modos, di un `var_dump($esp);` te sigue mostrando 9,000 líneas debes verificar la consulta que estás haciendo a la API, es muy probable que la misma tenga formas de filtrar los datos, de forma que te devuelva solamente el dato que vas a usar, no 9,000 líneas, que más adelante podrían ser millones de líneas si la API creciera. Es un elemento importante a optimizar, en caso de que siga enviando todos esos datos.

Comment: Lo voy a verificar!

Answer (score 2):

Es en la forma con la que accedes a la propiedad nombre, como tu endpoint es tipo **POST** debes de acceder a los datos así:

```
$this->post('agregar', function(Request $request, Response $response){

  $param  = $request->getParseBody();
  $nombre = $param['nombre'];
  $sql    = "INSERT INTO especialidad (nombre) VALUES(:nombre)"; 

  try{
    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);

    $stmt->execute(); 

    echo '{"notice": {"text": "Especialidad Agregada"}';

  } catch(PDOException $e){
    echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage(). '}';
  }

});
```